# How Apache and ProFTPD should work together, users and groups ect

Tags: apache-2.4, users, groups, proftpd

I have Apache server running on `apache:apache` and ProFTPD running on `ftpuser:ftpgroup`, all my websites are under `/var/www/` which is owned by `root:root`.

So the question is when I create a new website directory `/var/www/website1` what user group should have, `apache:apache` or `ftpuser:ftpgroup`.

If I make it `apache:apache` I am not able to upload any files from ftp.

I have tried some directives in ProFtpd conf, but doesnt work.

```
ServerType Standalone
<IfModule mod_cap.c>
   CapabilitiesEngine on
   CapabilitiesSet +CAP_CHOWN
</IfModule>
<Directory /var/www>
   UserOwner apache
   GroupOwner apache
   Umask 002 003
</Directory>
```

And I have added my ftpuser to apache group
`ftpuser : ftpgroup apache`

but sitll doesnt work.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can always add the user *apache* to the group *ftpgroup* and visa versa.